# Convert multiline clipboard text to comma delimited list

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

How would I convert multi-line clipboard data to a comma delimited list with a specific string in front of it?

For example if a user copied:

Alpha

Bravo

Charlie

I would want it to convert it to **mySpecificString: [Alpha, Bravo, Charlie]**

How would I do this?

I supposed I could do:

```
   dim clipconv as string
clipconv =  My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
```

and then split each line of **clipconv** into seperate strings and then do

`"MySpecificString: " & **clipboardLineOne** & ", " **ClipboardLineTwo** & ", "` etc...

but I don't know how it would account for the fact that the number of lines the clipboard will have is unknown....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is the answer to your problem

```
dim clipconv as string
clipconv =  My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()
Dim lines = clipconv.Split(New string() { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
Dim result = "MySpecificString: [" & String.Join(",", lines) & "]"
```

String.Join will take the array of string generated by the String.Split method and will concatenate the strings using the separator passed as first parameter, the remainder of your string (the prefix part and the suffix part) could be added separately before and after the working of String.Join

Comment: Amazing thanks! Do you by chance know how to take it one step further?

I wanted to make an alternate version of CTRL+C to where if the user pressed CTRL+H for example (could be any key) while this program was running in the background, it would copy whatever text they have highlighted to the clipboard, and then run this conversion on it.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to close this question and open a new one. The new subject is a lot more complex.